# TortoiseHg without context menu commands

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, tortoisehg

TortoiseHG's context menu entries [totally mess up Windows 7 explorer's context menu's appearance](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/114/shell.png), and I can get by fine with the hg command line tools. However Tortoise Overlay icons are must-have for me.

How can I disable TortoiseHg's context menu commands but still have the Tortoise Overlay icons appear in hg repository folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it appears to be fixed in the latest TortoiseHg - if you still have the issue, try upgrading.

Comment: +1, this was issue 466 http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/466/context-menu-changes-its-appearance-after-installing-tortoisehg and was fixed in 0.9.1

Answer (score 6):

To disable or add items to the context menu:

- Right click to bring up the context menu
- Select TortoiseHg ----> Explorer Extension Settings
- To Remove : Hide context menu except for repositories
- Or Use these settings to add or remove context menu items.

Comment: I used the 3rd option.. how do I bring it back now?

Comment: no option found in all tabs "Hide context menu except for repositories"

Comment: Holding shift while right clicking will display the context menus normally, just like the other tortoise products.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove following Windows registry keys using "regedit.exe" tool.
Before removing these, **please create backup of registry.**
And note that I cannot guarantee if you get any problem.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseHgCMenu
```

Comment: Did you restart Windows after removing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseHg\\tortoisehg.dll"
```

To re-enable shell extension:

```
regsvr32 "C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseHg\\tortoisehg.dll"
```

Comment: This would totally disable the shell extension, which I don't want (I only want to get rid of the context menu entries)

Comment: This didn't work for me under Windows 10 64-bit with TortoiseHg 3.3. The dll doesn't exist. I also tried with "ThgShellx64.dll", but this didn't work.